# bindingResult.hasErrors() always returns false

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I have problem with form validation in spring. bindingResult.hasErrors() always return false.Here is method from my Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveEmployee")
    public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") @Valid Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult){

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            bindingResult.getAllErrors().forEach(error->{
                System.out.println(error.getObjectName() + "" + error.getDefaultMessage());
            });

            return new ModelAndView("employeeForm","employee",employee);

        }else{
            try{

                userService.saveUser(employee.getUser());
                employeeService.addEmployee(employee);

            }catch(UserAlreadyExistException userExists){
                return new ModelAndView("/employeeForm","message","Account with this username/email already exists.");
            }

            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employees","employees",employeeService.getAllEmployees());
        }
    }
```

Here is my Employee class with annotations:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String surname;

    @ManyToOne
    private Task task;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;
}
```

I have here variables with annotations like @NotNull, @Size, @NotEmpty.

And here I have maven dependencies what I have tried to use:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What if you use `Errors` instead of `BindingResult`?

Comment: It is the same, errors.hasErrors() is always false.